# How a group cocycle becomes a group coboundary in a smaller group

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $A$ be a group. Then we choose that $B$ is a subgroup of $A$.

Let us write the cohomology group cocycle of $A$, as $\alpha_{d}(\{a\}) \in H^d(A,U(1))$ where $\{a\}$ is a shorthand for a set of $a_j \in A$ for $j=1,2, \dots$.

> (1) For any given subgroup $B$ (here $B$ may not be a trivial group), what are the conditions on the subgroup $B \subset A$ that the injective group homomorphism $$B \overset{i}{\to} A$$ 
>    such that
>   $$   \alpha_{d}(\{b\})$$
>   is a coboundary (namely, a trivial element) in $H^d(B,U(1))$?

-

> (2) What are the conditions that there exists a group homomorphism $$A \overset{f}{\to} B$$ 
>   where we name $f(a)=b$ for any $a \in A$ and some $b \in B$, such that
>   $$\alpha_{d}(\{f(a)\})=   \alpha_{d}(\{b\})$$
>   is a coboundary (namely, a trivial element) in $H^d(B,U(1))$?

We can consider $A$ and $B$ are finite groups.

p.s. Bonus questions: What if $A$ and $B$ are Lie groups?

Comment: Are you talking about the map in cohomology induced by the inclusion $B\subseteq A$? I'm a little confused by the homomorphism $f:A\to B$, which induces a map in the other direction.

Comment: Right. Usually if one has a subgroup $B\leq A$ and a homomorphism $f:A\to B$, one insists that $f$ is a *retraction*, meaning that $f|_B=\mathrm{id}_B$.  Otherwise, what's the point of thinking of $B$ as a subgroup?  In this case, writing $i$ for the inclusion $B\to A$, we have $i^*\circ f^*=\mathrm{id}_B^*$, so $f^*$ is necessarily injective.

Comment: Thank you for the nice comments. I am not 100% sure which way works, thus I take the suggestion and add a new possibility (1).

Comment: For (1) you can always take $B$ to be the trivial group, provided $d>0$. On the other hand, (2) does not make sense, as cohomology is contravariant on the group.

Comment: For (1), there are other subgroups $B$ of $A$, such that $B$ is not a trivial group, but (1) still holds.

Comment: As for your bonus question: unless you are considering some other cohomology theory for Lie groups, they are just groups, so nothing changes.

Comment: But your question is whether there exist such subgroups or not. And the answer is therefore yes, there is always such a subgroup.

Comment: My 1st question should be meaningful if we take the subgroup $B$ not a trivial group. We should try to make the most nontrivial observations on this.

Comment: Your questions may be meaningful, but that doesn't mean either of them admit a useful answer. A complete characterization is surely impossible. Do you want necessary conditions? Sufficient conditions?

Comment: One condition for (1) is: if the order of the cohomology class of $\alpha$ is not divisible by some prime dividing the order of $A$, then take $B$ to be a cyclic group of order that prime.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one possible sufficient condition for (1). Suppose $B$ is normal in $A$, then you have an extension of groups
$$
1 \to B\stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} A \stackrel{q}{\longrightarrow} A/B\to 1,
$$
where $q:A\to A/B$ is the map to the quotient group. Then $\alpha\in H^d(A;M)$ will have $$0=i^*\alpha\in H^d(B;M)$$ if there exists some $$\gamma\in H^d(A/B;M)$$ such that $\alpha=q^*\gamma$. (Here I am assuming that the coefficient module $M$ comes from a module over $A/B$, or equivalently, it becomes trivial when regarded as a $B$-module.)

When $d=1$ this sufficient condition is also necessary, as can be seen by looking at the 5-term exact sequence of low-dimensional cohomology groups coming from the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence of the extension. The same spectral sequence also hints that necessary conditions may be hard to come by in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, +1, this is a good type of answer that I am happy to receive.

Comment: @Mark Grant, Actually, why do you wrote $0=i^*\alpha\in H^d(A;M)$ instead of $0=i^*\alpha\in H^d(B;M)$? Should it be trivial in the cohomology group of $B$? (Is that the same as trivial in the cohomology group of $A$?)

Comment: @wonderich: good catch. Now corrected.